# How do I choose the right Websocket API

Tags: server, websockets, client

I'm doing a project where I have to control a live DALI controller and I'm sending data from the website to the controller with Websocket.

How do I know what Websocket to use?

At the moment I'm learning websocket, and going with the "socket.io" module running it with nodejs.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I'm asking because, i looked at the documentation for socket.io, and it said it was not recommended for real applications, so now i begin to think, i'm using the wrong websocket application,

what i believe i need to be able to send to the server, is changes with a slider, bottons that redirect to the specific memory, and a two way communication, so that when the clients/users changes the light, it sends the data straight to the server which, sends the data to the controller